# how does print deal with binary data and how it display it and how python bytes function works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, binary, hex

If I typed this code the output will be : b'd'

```
a = bytes([100])
print(type(a))
print(a)
```

I know that d in hex is number 100 and it seems like python print show me that the data are of type binary due to the letter be in the output so why is the result of when i store decimal number 100 as binary in variable which will be 1100100

so

```
a = 1100100    #in binary
```

and type(a) are also return binary type

so what is the reason for print function to print as binary ( b ) letter at start and at the same time represent number by its ASCII hex representation which is d

or is it because stored number is hex or what exactly is going on cause its so confusing for me right
now so if someone can answer these questions

- how is variable a represented in the meomery now
- why print show this weird behavior at least for me
- and is variable a hex or a binary number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b` letter is short for bytes. So its neither a hex or a binary number, it's a list of bytes. The default `__str__` function of bytes, which is used when you call `print(a)` tries to decode the bytes to string, that's why you're seeing the letter d.

Comment: Yeah, try `a = bytes([100, 101, 102])` will give you `b'def'`